# Html Helper is not detecting the model in ASP.Net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my current project i have to  implement Dynamically loading tree menu from database in ASP.Net MVC3 Razor.The below structure shows my Menu Model.
Level of Expertise in MVC3: Beginner

> MenuId Name ParentMenuId OrderBy
>
> 1   Item1       Null     1 2   Item2       Null     2 3   Item 2.1
>   2       1 4   Item 2.1.1   3        1 5   Item 2.1.2   3        2

for that i have done the following things
1.Created Htmlhelper Contains static  classes for Menus and sub menus,
2.Created Model for  Menu,
3.added HtmlHelper namespace to views/web.config

**When we debug the code it shows an error that value cannot be null.But my db contains the data ie count =11
The error is due to menu counting to Zero.So how to solve this because menu table contains 11 rows of data?**

**Error**

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 14:         { Line 15:             string
>   htmloutput=string.Empty; Line 16:             if (menu.Count() > 0)
>   Line 17:             { Line 18:                 htmloutput += "";
>
> Source File: D:\VS
>   Projects\Elixir\Elixir\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs    Line: 16
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source] 
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +4164811
>
>   Elixir.HtmlHelpers.HtmlHelperExtensions.ParentMenus(HtmlHelper html,
>   IEnumerable`1 menu) in D:\VS
>   Projects\Elixir\Elixir\HtmlHelpers\HtmlHelperExtensions.cs:16
>   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Menus_cshtml.Execute() in d:\VS
>   Projects\Elixir\Elixir\Views\Home\Menus.cshtml:4
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String
>   partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter
>   writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection) +279
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
>   String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
>   +113    System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName) +31
>   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.b_*2() in d:\VS
>   Projects\Elixir\Elixir\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:16
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.<>c*_DisplayClassb.b__9(TextWriter
>   tw) +283    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter
>   writer) +12    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult
>   result) +67    ASP._Page_Views_Shared__LayoutUser_cshtml.Execute() in
>   d:\VS Projects\Elixir\Elixir\Views\Shared_LayoutUser.cshtml:136
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +207
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +81
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
>   System.Web.WebPages.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6(TextWriter
>   writer) +102    System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter
>   writer) +12    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult
>   result) +67
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) +66
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +262
>
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) +220
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +303    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19()
>   +23    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +260
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass1e.b*_1b()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +343
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
>   +97    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +12    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62    System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7 
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
>   +22    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8862381    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

**HTML HELPER CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using Elixir.Models;

namespace Elixir.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string ParentMenus(this HtmlHelper html,IEnumerable<Menus> menu)
        {
            string htmloutput=string.Empty;
            if (menu.Count() > 0)
            {
                htmloutput += "<ul class='side-navigation accordion' id='nav-accordion'>";
                var MainMenu = from mainMenu in menu where mainMenu.MainMenuId == null orderby mainMenu.MenuOrder select mainMenu;
                foreach(Menus m in MainMenu)
                {
                    htmloutput += "<li>";
                    htmloutput += "<li><i class='icon-home'>";
                    htmloutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.LinkName, m.ActionName, m.ControllerName);
                    htmloutput += "</li>";
                    htmloutput += "</li></i>";
                }
                htmloutput += "</ul>";
            }
            return htmloutput;

        }

        public static string SubMenu(this HtmlHelper html, IEnumerable<Menus> SubMenu, int MenuId)
        {
            string htmlOutput = string.Empty;
            if (SubMenu.Count() > 0)
            {
                htmlOutput += "<ul class='side-navigation accordion' id='nav-accordion'>";
                var subMenu = from SMenu in SubMenu where SMenu.MainMenuId == MenuId orderby SMenu.MenuOrder select SMenu;
                foreach (Menus m in subMenu)
                {
                    htmlOutput += "<li>";
                    htmlOutput += "<li><i class='icon-home'>";
                    htmlOutput += LinkExtensions.ActionLink(html, m.LinkName, m.ActionName, m.ControllerName);
                    htmlOutput += "</li>";
                    htmlOutput += "</li></i>";
                }
                htmlOutput += "</ul>";
            }
            return htmlOutput;
        }

    }
}
```

**Controller Code**

```
public ActionResult Menus()
        {
            var MMenu = ment.Menu.ToList();
            return PartialView(MMenu);
        }
```

**Menu.cshtml ( Partial Layout)**

```
@model IEnumerable<Elixir.Models.Menus>

<div>
    @Html.Raw(@Html.ParentMenus(Model))



    </div>
```

**Index Page**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Elixir ERP V1.0 Beta";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="scroll-top">
            <a href="#" class="tip-top" title="Go Top"><i class="icon-arrow-up"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="left-bar merge-left">
            <!-- SEARCH BAR -->
            <!-- LEFT NAV -->
          @section leftnav{

             <div class="left-nav">
             @Html.Partial("Menus");
             </div>


          }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Menu Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Elixir.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_Menus")]
    public class Menus
    {
        [Key]
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public int MenuOrder { get; set; }
        public int? MainMenuId { get; set; }
        public string LinkName { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**Error**

Comment: The error is because `menu` is null - on this line here : `if (menu.Count() > 0)`

Comment: @StuartLC But the database table have the values and count =11.That means model is not filling with value isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your **Menu.cshtml** supposed to be **Menus.cshtml**?

If so, you're calling it as a partial on this line:

```
@Html.Partial("Menus");
```

But you're not giving it a model.

Try using

```
@Html.Action("Menus")
```